# Access Elements of a DOJO DIV

Tags: dojo

I have two Hyper Links on to a DOJO DIv

```
var create = dojo.create("div",{
            id:"create_links",
            className:"iconRow1",
            innerHTML:"<a class='popupLink' href='javascript:openCreateDialog()'>Create </a> <span>|</span><a  href='javascript:openUploadDialog()'>Batch </a>"
        },dojo.query(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar")[0]);
```

On click of the Batch Hyperlink , i have a function

```
function openUploadDialog()
{

// Here i want to disable the Create Hyper Link  tried this way
dojo.byId('create_links')[1].disabled=true; // Not working 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See whether i can answer your question.

HTML Part:

```
<div id="create_links">
<a href="#">g</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">h</a>
</div>
```

JS Part:

```
   dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var a = dojo.query("#create_links a")[1];
    dojo.connect(a,'click',function(e){
      console.log(e.preventDefault())
    })
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kiran, you are treating the return of `dojo.byId('create_links')` like an array when that statement will return to you a node on the dom.

Also, hyperlinks don't support a disabled attribute to prevent them from being actionable. You could probably create a click handler that returns false to accomplish this type of functionality, or like @rajkamal mentioned, calling e.preventDefault(). @rajkamal also provides a good solution to selection the link properly.